# scala class extend a trait with generic which is a type of a field

Tags: scala, generics

I want to write code like this:

```
trait A[S]
class B {
    class BI
}
class C(val b: B) extends A[b.BI] // won't compile
```

Which won't compile. 
So I write this:

```
class C[BI0] private (val b: B) extends A[BI0]
object C {
  def apply(b: B): C[b.BI] = new C(b)
}
```

But that looks ugly. Is there a better implementation?

Why do I have this question? I conceive a example:

```
trait Store[Goods] {
    def sell(goods: Goods): Unit
}
class CarFactory {
    def make(): Car = new Car
    class Car
}
class CarStore(val factory: CarFactory) extends Store[factory.Car]{//can't compile
    def sell(car: factory.Car): Unit = {}
}
```

I don't want to use `CarFactory#Car` because this car store only sell cars of the factory `factory`.

Comment: What is `BI0`? A concrete type?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I think it's just the name of `C2`'s type parameter...

Comment: I want `BI0` to be the type `b.BI`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a better way. What you have is a fairly standard way of working around using path-dependent types in class declarations. Alternatively, you can use type members:

```
trait A { type S }

class B { class BI }

class C(val b: B) extends A { type S = b.BI }
```

Comment: Oh! That looks better. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what are you trying to do here, but does this work for you?

```
trait A[S] 
class B {
  class BI
} 
class C(val b: B) extends A[B#BI]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this trick. But I need a path dependent type `b.BI`, not only `B#BI`.

Comment: I do not understand your question then :)